# php update script failing to work

Tags: php, sql, edit

bellow is the code for a PHP edit script. I am aware it is not protected as it is an example however it doesn't seem to work, from what i can see syntactically it is OK but i may be missing something.

The code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$connect){
die("Connection failed:" . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test",$connect);


if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_venues SET venue_id='$_POST[id]', venue_name='$_POST[name]', venue_description ='$_POST[desc]', venue_address ='$_POST[address]', venue_type ='$_POST[type]' WHERE venue_id='$_POST[hidden]'"; 
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $connect);


};

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_venues ORDER BY venue_id";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql,$connect);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Venue ID</th>
<th>Venue Name</th>
<th>Venue Description</th>
<th>Venue Address</th>
<th>Venue Type</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

echo"<form action=venuelist.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='id' value='" . $record['venue_id'] . "'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='"  . $record['venue_name'] . "'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='desc' value='"  . $record['venue_description'] . "'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='address' value='"  . $record['venue_adress'] . "'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='type' value='"  . $record['venue_type'] . "'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='" . $record['venue_id'] . "'> </td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='update' " . "'> </td>";
echo "</form>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

It displays the data proving its not a connection issue however the data stops showing when a apostrophe is present in the row. The main issue is it refuses to update the field.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.  You can also see http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives and explanation of the danger.

Answer (score 1):

If the value includes an apostrophe it will break the html.

e.g. Your rendered html will look something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='it's a problem'>
```

Most frameworks will automatically prevent issues like this by automatically escaping problematic characters so you don't need to do it manually. (e.g. CakePHP and many others)

Comment: I see, is there a way around this?

Comment: Working around this manually can be deceptively complicated and dangerous, from a security standpoint. I highly recommend using a framework which will take care of it automatically.

Comment: Thanks I understand ill take a look, any ideas on why the update/edit function is not working?

Comment: You will have the same issue in your sql update statement. e.g. "UPDATE tbl_venues SET venue_id='it's a problem'..."

To help understand what is going on... a very hacky solution would be to use mysql_real_escape_string() (addslashes()) for creating the SQL and escape the apostrophe when generating the html. e.g. Replace the apostrohpe so your html looks like: <input name='x' value='ab&apos;c'>. You can see how it quickly gets complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method for escaping single quotes in your output. It uses [the php function str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$myString = "testing 'this' is a problem";
$myString = str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $myString);
echo $myString;
```

As far as how to remove those single quotes *on the way into the database*, take a look at prepared statements. It's a reliable way to protect your database from SQL injection. In particular take a look at [this canonical question and answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Your update statement is not working because single quotes break the SQL query. So you'll have to deal with those some way, and prepared statements is the best practice there.